# Jenkins VM slave disconnects from master

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, virtualbox

I have a configuration set up where I have a Windows Server 2003 VM (VirtualBox 4.2.22, vmdk) running on a Windows 7 host. The slave-agent client runs on the Windows Server 2003 VM with Java 1.7.0_80. On the master, Jenkins 1.625.1 LTS is installed with Java 1.8.0_66. During a build, the Jenkins slave node will go offline:

```
Slave went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken: java.io.EOFException
   at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$3.run(NioChannelHub.java:613)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
   at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This link is the only link I can find that's related to this issue: [[JENKINS-31050] Slave goes offline during the build](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31050). Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting the slave and the master? which protocol? JNLP? As service?